# Angular custom webpack with multiple targets

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, web-worker

In my application I'm using [webpack with multiple targets](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#multiple-targets).

Basically I have one for the application code and one for the web worker code, i.e. sth like:

```js
const browserConfig =  {
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
//...
}
const workerConfig = {
    target: "webworker",
    entry: {
        decoder: "./worker-stuff.ts"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
// ...
});

module.exports = [browserConfig, workerConfig];
```

Now I'm trying to integrate my application into an Angular application as a component using [custom webpack configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack)
The `browserConfig` part is already handled by Angulars internal WebPack configuration so I just need to append the `workerConfig`.
So this is how my custom webpack config looks like:

```js
const workerConfig = {
    target: "webworker",
    entry: {
        worker: "./worker-stuff.ts"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
// ...
});

module.exports = [workerConfig];
```

And I use it like this in angular.json:

```js
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
            },
```

Unfortunately it seems Angular can not handle arrays of configurations:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property '0'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
```

Removing the square brackets does also not work b/c then the Angular and my workerConfig get merged and that's not what I want.

Am I doing sth. wrong or is it just not possible to have multiple targets with custom webpack configuration?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?